# 2 Domains pointing to hosting but only 1 is responsive

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design, dns, hosting

This is a rather strange problem. I am a wordpress developer and I migrated a local site to my clients host package at fasthosts.co.uk. The theme I am using has the normal responsive layout seen in most modern themes.

My client has two domains registered to the host package. (1) is the official one for the package and the other(2) has been forwarded to the same directory on the server.

Domain1 loads the website and on a phone it is responsive and looks fine. Domain 2 loads the same site but the page just loads in full even on the phone and is not responsive and looks really small.

I do not know where to begin to know why one is responsive and one is not if they are both pointing to exactly the same files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any error in console when you access with second domain ?

Comment: Actually there are some lines that say error in parsing value for background-image. Decleration dropped. But that shows on the working site too.

Comment: I'm not sure what they have done (fasthosts support are looking into it) but now domain2 jumps straight to domain1 and it is fine, but I want the address at the top to remain saying domain2 and it does not.

Comment: Might be issue in their side if there is no issue in console.

Comment: Just got this back from support, but it does not help me with having both domains showing. Their fix just forwards domain2 to domain1 and the address bar changes to domain1.. I will follow up with them.   "I have further investigated from my end, the reason why the web forwarding for reflexologysouthwest.co.uk was not properly working from the mobile device because the Redirection type from your Web forwarding option to 302 - Moved Temporarily.
 
The masked option will make a it own frame that was the reason why if you use your mobile device it will not show as a Mobile device mode website."